# Fetch local files with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, fetch-api

In a browser environment fetching a local file is quite trivial: one just need to start a server (using MAMP, XAMP, Mac's Python server, etc...), and then doing:

```
fetch("./foo.txt").then(etc...)
```

However, in Node.js this simple task has been a challenge. I've tried the same snippet using Node 18 (which comes with an experimental fetch API), but I'm always getting an *invalid URL* error:

> TypeError: Failed to parse URL from foo.bar
>
> [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL

I've tried installing [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), but I'm getting the same error. I could start a local server for node like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), but it tells me to go to http://localhost:8080 to see the server, that is, using the browser, but the issue is that I can do that without node, using only a node build is the whole point.

My question is: is it possible to fetch a local file in a node build (Sublime Text, VS Code etc...), *without* using a browser? (note: I can do it with `fs`, but in my question I'd like to discuss `fetch` only)

Comment: In node it's quite trivial as well: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options

Comment: You can use the [fs (file system)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module in NodeJS to read from the local filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is it possible to fetch a local file in a node build (Sublime Text, VS Code etc...), without using a browser? (note: I can do it with fs, but in my question I'd like to discuss fetch only)

The Node.js implementation of `fetch` does not currently support `file:` scheme URLs…

---

> ```
> fetch("file:///tmp/123").then(r => r.text()).then(d => console.log(d));
> ```

reports:

> Error: not implemented... yet...

---

…nor (it appears) does it resolve a relative path to a `file:` scheme URI.

You should use the `fs` module.

Comment: ...which might be for the better, actually, to avoid automatically extending an SSRF vulnerability into an LFI.