# fetch() data from a local JSON file

Tags: json, parsing, fetch, urlfetch

I'm in a pickle with the fetch method on a local JSON file even though the URL path seems correct.

Thanks in advance

```
   async function fetchLacsfromJSON(){
    try {
        const reponse = await fetch('/app/lacs.json', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            } })
            if (reponse.ok){
              const lacsData= await reponse.json();
              return lacsData;
          }
          else  {   
            console.error(`Erreur HTTP : ${reponse.status} - ${reponse.statusText}`);} 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Une erreur s'est produite : ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
```

the Error Message  was : Failed to parse URL from /app/lacs.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ras36.jpg)
i was expecting to receive this on the console:

```
[{ "id":"1",
    "nom":"Lac d’Annecy",
    "region":"Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes"
    },
    {"id":"2",
     "nom":"Lac de Sainte Croix",
     "region":"Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur"
    },
    {"id":"3",
     "nom":"Lac du Salagou",
     "region":"Occitanie"
    }
]
```

Comment: you cannot load files from disk, it needs to either be served by a web server or if its a local file, you can then include/import it and use it directly

Comment: you can do this `import jsonData from 'path/to/myJson.json'`

Comment: or `let jsonData = require('path/to/myJson.json');`

Comment: Cross reference in case of nodejs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74769009/18667225

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help ! I deleted :
{
"type":"module"
} in my package.json ( cause I tried node-fetch, import ...from) => no use

and my asynchronous function with the fetch on (the local JSON file).

And just typed  in my mainController:

```
const lacsData =require('../lacs.json');
```

was enough after I deleted the async/fetch combo.

I retrieved my data with .map method on my data and it works